# How to load a model in another controller using a custom PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

My application have this folders stucture:

> - **application**
>
> > - **library**
> >
> > > - Model.php
> > > - Controller.php
> > > - View.php
> >
> > **models**
> >
> > - *Settings_Model.php*
> > - *Home_Model.php*
>
> > - **controllers**
> >
> >   > - *settings.php*
> >   > - *home.php*
> > - **views**
> >
> >   > - ***settings***
> >   >
> >   >   > - *index.php*
> >   > - ***home***
> >   >
> >   >   > - *index.php*
>
> index.php
>
> .htaccess

**library/Model.php**

```
 class Database extends PDO{
        public function __construct($DB_TYPE, $DB_HOST, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS){
              parent::__construct($DB_TYPE.':host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);       
        }
  }
```

**library/Controller**

```
 class Controller{

      function __construct(){       
           $this->view = new View();
      }

      public function loadModel($name){
           $path = 'application/models/' . $name . '_model.php';

           if(file_exists($path)){
                require 'application/models/' . $name . '_model.php';
                $modelName = $name . '_Model';
                $this->model = new $modelName();            
           }
      }
 }
```

**library/View**

```
 class View{

      function __construct(){       
           $this->view = new View();
      }

      public function render($name){
           require 'application/views/' . $name . '.php';
      }
 }
```

In **Models folder** I created this model called **Settings_Model.php** : *models/Settings_Model.php*

```
 class Settings_Model extends Model{
    public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

    function settings(){
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mv_settings`");
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       return $stmt->fetch();
    }       
 }
```

In **Controllers folder** I have this Controller called **settings.php** :
 *controllers/settings.php*

```
class Settings extends Controller {

    function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

    public function index(){    
        $this->view->settings = $this->model->settings();   
        $this->view->render('settings/index');      
    }   
}
```

And In **Views folder** I created a folder called **settings** and inside this folder I created an **index.php** file:
 *settings/index*

and this is how to call the settings method inside settings/index:

> `$this->settings->fieldName;`

So now when we go to **Home** view, I did the same procedure: 
 - create a Home_Model class and inside this model I created the same settings method:

```
 class Home_Model extends Model{
    public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

    function settings(){
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mv_settings`");
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       return $stmt->fetch();
    }       
 }
```

and then goes to the controllers folder and create **Home** controller:

```
class Home extends Controller {

    function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

    public function index(){    
        $this->view->settings = $this->model->settings();   
        $this->view->render('home/index');      
    }   
}
```

and then call the settings method inside home/index:

> `$this->settings->fieldName;`

What Im asking is how to avoid not to create the same method *settings* again and again each time we need to call that method in another view file???

> **NB**: Im still a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in your controller

```
class Settings extends Controller {
   function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->model('Settings_Model');
   }
   public function index(){    
     $this->view->settings = $this->Settings_Model->settings();   
     $this->view->render('settings/index');      
   }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but My question is how not recreate the same settings method in every single model file? 
 and how to call the same method in different controllers?

Comment: you can call model in your controller(controller.php) in contructor. then you can use its functions

Comment: In your case, you can call model by in `constructor` of `controller.php`
     `$CI =& get_instance();`
    `$CI->load->model('Settings_Model');`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't know what $CI =& get_instance(); means? and how to use it. Kindly give me a clear exemple so that a newbie like me can understand well :)

Comment: you can check the codeigniter userguide. It has example and explanation also.
 https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the same settings() function in all models then you should create it in Base model.php.

```
class Model{


  function settings(){
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mv_settings`");
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       return $stmt->fetch();
    }

  }
```

then your settings model need to be like

```
 class Settings_Model extends Model{
    public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

 }
```

and your Home_model

```
 class Home_Model extends Model{
    public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}

 }
```

Now you can access settings() in all your models extending Model, no need to create it again and again.